# count of "prepare statement" used by Electric Commander is increasing heavily

Tags: mysql, build-process

We use Electric Commander with MySQL, Electric Commander DB is in shared MySQL Env. Every day prepare statement increasing heavily and reaches the default value in a week, as soon as default value is reached other application started to fail. Limit set is one hundred thousand. We are in MySQL 5.6, Our DBA pulled out last two weeks data and found that count of prepare statement created and closed by each session, to our surprise no stmt got closed.

Did anybody facing this issue ? How do we resolve this ? Is there any calculation to come up with prepare stmt max count value ?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

> to our surprise no stmt got closed.

Prepared statements need to be deallocated.
If you have a long running session creating many prepared statements dynamically and never cleaning up, this cause a resource leak.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/deallocate-prepare.html